# Class instance assignment causing exception within a try catch

Tags: javascript, class, jestjs, try-catch

I am developing a web-scrapping component that gets specific data on a webpage and makes an instance of an object which is pushed onto the end of an array.

The code does not throw any exceptions in this form, but when I change the object to the initialisation of a class the following error occurs in my jest test.

> node:internal/process/promises:246
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cost')".] {
> code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'

The variation of the code with the bug is shown here:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = "https://www.domain.com.au/rent/north-strathfield-nsw-2137/?bedrooms=3&price=0-650&excludedeposittaken=1";
debugger;

class Rental {
    constructor(cost, street, suburb) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.street = street;
        this.suburb = suburb;
    }
}

// Using the puppeteer module, we can create a headless chrome browser to scrap the 'domain.com.au' website for cost, street, suburb which we add to an array of objects. 
function scrapeApartments(inputUrl) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { //TODO: figure out what this promise stuff is 
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        
        try {
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(inputUrl);

            // returns the price, street and suburb data in an object. for each of the apartments listed on the inputUrl
            let apartments = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let results = [];
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('.css-qrqvvg');
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    try {
                        //parses the cost, street values from the elements in page
                        const cost = parseInt(item.querySelector('.css-mgq8yx').innerText.slice(1, 4));
                        let street = item.querySelector('.css-iqrvhs').innerHTML;
                        street = street.slice(0, street.search('<'));
                        const suburb = item.querySelectorAll('.css-iqrvhs')[1].querySelectorAll('span')[0].innerHTML;

                        const currentObj = new Rental(cost, street, suburb); // BUG HERE: so there is something about this line that is causing the issue where it skips over the code due to some bug
                        results.push(currentObj);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log('ERROR IN INDIVIDUAL ITEMS');
                    }
                });
                return results;
            })
            return resolve(apartments);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR: ', e)
        } finally{
            browser.close();
        }
    })
}

async function callingPromise() {
    return await scrapeApartments(url);
    // const result = await scrapeApartments(url);
    // console.log(result);
}
callingPromise();
module.exports = scrapeApartments;
```

The bug is on in the currentObj declaration.

I have tried using the class and it's initialisation in another file and it works as expected.

On another note I would appreciate any criticisms over my coding practises as well, apologies as I am relatively untrained in try-catch and jest.